# I can't find why threading isn't working in my code

Tags: python, sockets, python-multithreading

I was trying to make a simple chat application using the socket module in Python. In my `client.py` file I created two functions, one for writing and one for receiving messages from the server. As it must be run simultaneously, I used the threading module. But it's not working and I don't have a clue why. Here's my code:

```
import socket
import threading

SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
PORT = 5050
HEADER = 1024
FORMAT = "utf-8"
socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.connect((SERVER, PORT))

def write():
    while True:
        message = input()
        socket.send(message.encode(FORMAT))
threading.Thread(write())
def receive():
    while True:
        try:
            msg = socket.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
            print(msg)
        except:
            print('You have been disconnected!')
            socket.close()
            break
         
write_thread = threading.Thread(target=write())
recv_thread = threading.Thread(target=receive())
recv_thread.start()
write_thread.start()
```

Comment: What is your problem? Does it have an error, or wrong output? What should the code do?

Answer (score 0):

Things to fix in the future:

1. (Line 4): I think what you want to do is `SERVER = "localhost"`
2. (Line 15): This is unused

Error:

```
write_thread = threading.Thread(target=write())
recv_thread = threading.Thread(target=receive())
```

Should be(else you call the functions instead of giving them as a parameter):

```
write_thread = threading.Thread(target=write)
recv_thread = threading.Thread(target=receive)
```